# Can't open any links in any applications (22.04 LTS)?

Tags: 22.04

I recently upgraded to 22.04, and the only problem is any links (whether in discord, visual studio code, email, etc) do NOT open external link(s).  I have to copy the link and paste into firefox, etc, for it to work.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firejail was the problem, don't know how it was installed thou.